# Cannot reach a service inside my docker-compose

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose

I'm new with Docker and I'm trying to create a project using Microservices with .Net Core. I've two services: **Identity.API** and **Writer.API**. Using docker-compose, I declare two services:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
 identity.api:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityapi
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Services/Identity/Identity.API/Dockerfile
  ports: 
   - "5100:80"
   - "5101:443"
  depends_on:
  - sqldata
  - rabbitmq
 
 writer.api:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}writerapi
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Services/Writer/Writer.API/Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "5200:80"
   - "5201:443"
  depends_on:
   - rabbitmq

 rabbitmq: # login guest:guest
  image: rabbitmq:3-management
  hostname: "rabbitmq"
  labels: 
   NAME: "rabbitmq"
  ports:
    - "4369:4369"
    - "5671:5671"
    - "5672:5672"
    - "25672:25672"
    - "15671:15671"
    - "15672:15672"
```

The first service is on 5100, the second on 5101. When I start the docker-compose, I can see this:

[image]

So if I try to open the first service, I can see swagger without any problem:

https://localhost:5101/swagger/index.html

But if I try to reach the second service, I've a not found.

https://localhost:5201/swagger/index.html

If I try to run **Writer.API** service alone in Docker, it runs just fine.

My swagger configuration at startup:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerConfiguration(
    this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
    {
        swaggerGenOptions.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = configuration["Swagger:ApiName"],
            Version = configuration["Swagger:ApiVer"]
        });

        //...
    });

    return services;
   
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPresentation(
        this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMappings();
        services.AddSwaggerConfiguration(configuration);

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
            "CorsPolicy",
             builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        return services;
    }
}

//Program.cs
builder.Services
    .AddApplication(configuration!)
    .AddInfrastructure(configuration!)
    .AddPresentation(configuration!);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//...
```

I really cannot understand how to reach the other service, and I cannot understand why the addresses are different. I'm missing something? For some reason on **Identity.API** docker create 4 addresses, for **Writer.API** there are only two addresses.

I really cannot understand what's wrong with this configuration. Any help?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you please share the code part of swagger config in startup.cs?

Comment: Just posted above :). It's the same for both services. Writer.Api runs fine if I run it directly in docker, without docker compose.

Comment: please share the related part in the Configure method as well, and I suggest first to comment the security parts to simplify the problem

Comment: Done as you can see above. But I think this not a swagger problem. I cannot reach the endpoint even with Postman. :/

Comment: Is the service still running after 10 seconds or it is stopped and also Could you use this line and comment the if condition "app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));" and one more thing is to delete the image and build it again

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand where the problem was. For some reason, Visual Studio creates a **docker-compose.override.yml** without the **Writer.API** service. So I opened the file and added my service just like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  identity.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

#SERVICE NOT ADDED AUTOMATICALLY! 
  writer.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

So not it seems to work just fine :/.